# How can I get code coverage with "coverage" / "coveralls"?

Tags: python, code-coverage

I would like to get my code (see https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt) coverage with coveralls and https://coveralls.io.

I already get it with `nosetests --with-coverage` which shows a coverage of 20%.

However, when I run `coveralls` it only shows

```
Submitting coverage to coveralls.io...
Coverage submitted!
Job #4.1
https://coveralls.io/jobs/2997583
```

When I run `coverage run setup.py test` I get

```
running test
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
```

It seems that I am using coverage.py wrong. How should I use it instead?

Comment: What if you run coverage this way: `nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=hwrt`?

Comment: what does it mean to run coverage in that way? In that way I don't run the python program `coverage` at all but the program `nosetests`, don't I?

Comment: Sure I mean `nosetests`.

Comment: Then I get http://pastebin.com/E2JMeLkN